# What is 0 mapped to in a Euclidean domain?

Tags: ring-theory

Let us suppose we have a Euclidean domain A, in which we have $a=q*d+r$. We know that there is a function $f:A\to Z$ such that for every $a\in A/0$, we have $f(a)>f(0)$. Also, $f(r)<f(d)$.

Is it necessary that $0$ in A be mapped to $0$ in $Z$? Or can it be mapped to any number, provided it satisfies the above axioms?

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the various possible definitions and their logcial relationships see A. G. Agargun, C. R. Fletcher,  [Euclidean Rings,](http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/math/issues/mat-95-19-3/pp-291-299.pdf) Tr. J. of Mathematics, 19, 1995, 291 - 299.